# Share Ethernet connection with second NIC (SmartTV)

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am having trouble sharing my wired internet connection with my SmartTV.

My setup is a single on-board Gigabit port (enp3s0) and a separate 100Mbit PCIe card (enp6s0).

The enp3s0 is connected directly to the RJ45 socket in the wall. It connects with DCHP and works flawlessly.

I wish to allow the SmartTV, which is connected via a cat5e cable to the second NIC enp6s0, to have full access to the internet connection.

The TV is a Samsung UE55HU7500. It's quite limited as to what settings I can change regarding networking. I can set it to "Get Settings Automatically" or enter the values for IP Address, Subnet Mask, Gateway and DNS Server.

Setting it to Automatic and connecting the TV to the wall works fine. I know this can be fixed with a switch, but right now that's not an option.

I have been trying for a while now but my limited networking skills are not really helping. Hopefully someone can provide me with a simple explanation of how to get this working.

Comment: @wjandrea: please use "reject and edit" more carefully in the future as these are lower-level users then you and not as accustomed to the rules yet.  Better to "accept and edit" and leave a comment then what you did...  Only when it's *really*  bad should you reject and edit.  If you disagree, [drop by in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to kick me!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using a GUI:** *(Only works for IPv4)*

1. Go in to the `Network Connections` setting
2. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
3. Select `Ethernet` then click create
4. Use the drop-down list by the device option to `enp6s0`, or the desired device.
5. Click the `IPv4 Settings` tab
6. Click on the drop-down box beside `Method`, and change it to `Shared to other computers`
7. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>, then <kbd>Close</kbd>

Note: *The TV, in this case, will not get an IP address registered by the router. It will still be able to access other LAN computers & the Internet, but other computers can't (without tunneling) access it.*

Comment: I hope I clarified well enough that this is meant to be done on the Ubuntu computer, not the TV.

Comment: That was extremely simple! Thanks a million for your help. Worked like a charm.

It's amazing how long I messed around with this and didn't come up with that!